# Where do I add the server-side integration part of Recaptcha 2 with the following form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to implement the new ReCaptcha 2 on a form on my site. I know how to add the client side portion into the form so that's not the issue. Problem is where exactly to implement the server side portion that contains the secret key?
This form uses a separate php file to process the form and upload the contents to a mysql database. All the tutorials I've found online seem to show everything on the same page as the form. That's where my confusion lies.

Here's the form itself. Note I've added the client side code but not put my actual key in yet..

```
<form name="sponsor-registration" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     action="sponsor-registration.php">
<div class="formcentered">
<div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="yourname" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Your Name:</div>
<br class="clearfloat" />
<div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="sponsorname" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Company Name:</div>
<br class="clearfloat" />
<div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="70" value="" required></div><div class="formlabel">Email:</div>
<br class="clearfloat" />
<div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="phone" size="30" maxlength="20" value=""></div><div class="formlabel">Phone</div>
<br class="clearfloat" />
<div class="formcenteredsmallcol"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekeywillgohere"></div></div>
<p class="pagecentered"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
</div>
</form>
```

Note the form uses "sponsor-registration" to process the form. Here is that file: sponsor-registration.php

```
<?php //start php tag
//include connect.php page for database connection
include('connect.php');
//if submit is not blanked i.e. it is clicked.
{
$sql="insert into sponsors2015(yourname, sponsorname, email, phone) values('".$_REQUEST['yourname']."', '".$_REQUEST['sponsorname']."',   '".$_REQUEST['email']."', '".$_REQUEST['phone']."')"; $res=mysql_query($sql); if($res)
{
Echo header('Location: sponsor-registration-success.php');
}
Else
{
Echo header('Location: sponsor-registration-problem.php');
}

}

?>
```

So do I add the server side scripts into "sponsor-registration.php" itself (and if so where in the form) or should I combine everything into the page with the html form like some of the tutorials I've seen? For some reason this part is just not making sense. I've tried a couple different places with the server-side scripts and the form will not validate properly and/or submit to the database.

I feel like this is a simple fix and I'm going to go "duh" when I see the solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Did you find out how this is done? I am having a very similar problem with this version integration... In my case I have the form and a phpmailer script in a separate file that processes the form to send it to my email. The simple part of the client side is done but should I include any file in my root folder, or invoke files from my phpmailer?

Comment: I actually ended up using Formmail by Tectite to process my form and also send an email of the form contents to an admin. Formmail has reCaptcha built into the form. You simply add your secret key to a line in the configuration section and it's done. So I really still don't know where to put the server side scripts in a phpmailer script other than Formmail. Still working on it though as I would like to better understand how it works and not just blindly implement everything with "prefab" scripts like Formmail. Having said that, Formmail is a pretty awesome script!!